# What in Maxwell's Equations Implies Magnetic Field Lines Concentrate in An Iron?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

It's often said in grade school level physics books that an iron will concentrate magnetic field lines.

How can this fact be inferred from Maxwell's equations?

Comment: implied by the existence of materials with either $\mu >> 1$ or with permanent magnetization $M$ being essentially independent of external bias

Comment: It can't be inferred from Maxwell's equations *alone*. You can see that it depends on the behavior of the material from the fact that there are materials that don't exhibit ferromagnetism.